# Clear stdout before `mocha --watch` re-runs

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I'd like to automatically execute `clear` between each test iteration with `mocha --watch`. Is there a nice way to automatically execute a command before (re)running mocha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I ended up doing it is using `--delay`, which lets you run your own async code before beginning the tests (using `global.run()`. Docs [here](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite)

`_.tests.js`:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;
child = exec('clear', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
    global.run();
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Mocha supports different [reporters](https://mochajs.org/#reporters), and the [`min`](https://mochajs.org/#min) reporter does exactly what you are looking for:

```
mocha run --recursive dist/tests --reporter min
```

It's especially helpful if used together with the `--watch` flag, as then the tests run constantly on file changes.